# PHP thinks it is writing to a .txt file, but it is actually not

Tags: javascript, php, fwrite, saving-data

I am currently writing a small website on which everybody can set if they will be present or not. Every visitor of the site can see who is going to be present and who is not. there is a small switch (a checkbox with CSS going over it) which indicates presence.

The thing i'm working on right now is a switch(checkbox) which will remember the state that it's in on page reload. The way i've done this is by writing to a simple .txt file on the server 'true' or 'false'. At startup it reads the state of the textfile. i also included a lot of console comments to see where it is going wrong, but now im stuck.

At the end of the comment when the checkbox is changed, it reads the .txt file with fread to check if fwrite worked. In the console it says that it wrote correctly (the .txt file reads the variable that it should according to the last writing.) But if I access the file trough my site www.example.eg/textfile.txt it says it hasn't changed. Also the checkbox state isn't saved on reload of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>


        <script>
        function startupfunction(){
        <?php //reading current state
        $myfile = fopen("switchstate.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $output = fread($myfile,filesize("switchstate.txt"));

        // $output = "42";
        ?>

        var data = '<?php echo $output; ?>';
        var startupsetting;

        console.log("the initial (startupfunction) reading out of .txt(var = data):" + data);
        if(data == "true"){
            console.log("The if(true) statement based on var data works. setting bool to TRUE to change to correct switchstate")
            startupsetting = true;
        }
        else{
            console.log("The if(true) statement based on var data works. setting bool to FALSE to change to correct switchstate")
            startupsetting = false;
        }
        document.getElementById("myCheck").checked=startupsetting;
        console.log("This is done by setting a bolleaan called startupsetting this is now equal to:" + startupsetting);

        var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
        console.log("Now reading the state of the switch? did it work (is it equal to line above)" + x)
        } //close startupfunction


        window.onload = startupfunction;                    //set state of checkbox(switch)

        </script>
        </head>

<body>




<style>                                                                                             
    .onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "WEL";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "NIET";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 18px; margin: 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 56px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
</style>




<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input onchange="myFunction();" type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myCheck">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myCheck">
        <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
        <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
</div>




<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myCheck").checked;
    console.log("now starting measuring changes, x value changing...")
    console.log("Value of x before flipping:"+ x);
    x = (x) ? false : true;
    console.log("Value of x after flipping:" + x);

    //if(x==true) blaablaablaa
    if(x == true){
            <?php   //write 0 back to .txt file onserver
            $myfile = fopen("switchstate.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $txt = "false";
            fwrite($myfile,$txt);

            ?>

            console.log("wrote false(using the if/true statement) to .txt...");
            console.log("starting reading .txt file")

            <?php //reading current state
            $myfile = fopen("switchstate.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $output = fread($myfile,filesize("switchstate.txt"));

            // $output = "42";
            ?>

            var data = '<?php echo $output; ?>';
            console.log("the .txt file now reads:" + data);

    }

    else{
            <?php   //write 0 back to .txt file onserver
            $myfile = fopen("switchstate.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $txt = "true";
            fwrite($myfile,$txt);

            ?>
            console.log("wrote true(using the else/false statement) to .txt...");
            console.log("starting reading .txt file")

            <?php //reading current state
            $myfile = fopen("switchstate.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
            $output = fread($myfile,filesize("switchstate.txt"));

            // $output = "42";
            ?>

            var data = '<?php echo $output; ?>';

            console.log("the .txt file now reads:" + data);

    }


}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is executed *server side*. So **all** your PHP code is executed 
*before you can even begin to see* the page. If you check your page source, you will see that the javascript function sent to the browser does actually next to nothing (the PHP code has been executed, and the Javascript is left with its **output** - which is empty). What you need is an AJAX callback to be executed on checkbox state change.

Comment: you should open the web page and view source code, that way you will see the javascript function can not call php code like that

Comment: Hi Bart, you should read [differences between client and server side programming](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) and then try to use AJAX(as @Iserni said) to send data from client to server. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** you need to beef up on client/server programming and AJAX callback to PHP code. Recommended a tutorial on PHP and jQuery. I'm going out on a limb here and suggest you check out http://www.w2ui.com for interface development (<sup><sub>and I'll now be flamed by everyone suggesting *their* favourite framework or library ;-)</sub></sup> )

---

You actually  need *two* files (at least). Only the second needs to be PHP. In the first, in Javascript, you intercept the checkbox change.

This is usually done using jQuery or similar, because it makes this kind of things very easy:

```
// this will only work if jQuery is loaded
$('#idOfMyCheckbox').on('change', function() {
    $.post(
        '/url/of/my/checkbox/saver',
        {
            state: $(this).val()
        },
        function(ret) {
            alert("The server replied: " + ret.message);
        }
    ).fail(function() {
        alert("something went very wrong");
    });
});
```

The PHP is called by the `$.post` AJAX, and will receive a `$_POST['state']` value.

```
<?php
     $fp = fopen("state.txt", "w");
     fwrite($fp, $_POST['state']); // DANGER WILL ROBINSON: NO ERROR CHECKING HERE.
     fclose($fp);
?>
```

## Debugging

Once you have your application, you need to know what it actually *does*. For example, loading the code above (once you supply it with the proper HTML, jQuery bindings etc.) should do exactly *nothing*, apart from loading the needed resources.

Then, changing the state of the checkbox should trigger a HTTP POST to the state-saving URL.

To verify this you will find useful either Chrome's WebTools or Firefox's Firebug extension. I guess you're already using something similar since you issue `console.log` calls. These tools also log resource usage and errors.

They also allow you to issue calls from the console interface, so you can e.g. run

```
$('#idOfYourCheckbox')
```

and verify it returns an array with exactly one object (otherwise, something went wrong with the selectors. I usually copy and paste and end up with `<input id="#myId">` instead of `<input id="myId">`, for example).

Then you can manually issue the `.post` call, and verify that it goes out and what the system returns. Above, I had not bothered adding the JSON return that the AJAX query requires:

```
 fclose($fp);
 Header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
 die(json_encode(array(
     'status'  => 'OK',
     'message' => 'It worked!',
 )));
```

(I did it out of laziness. My bad. But it all goes to show that you shouldn't expect to just plug a piece of code in the site and have it working -- you need to know what it does, *what it is expected to do*, and even then you'll need to fiddle with it a good bit).

## Self-contained example (with status loading too)

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="mycheck" type="checkbox" />
    </body>
    <script>
        // jQuery main function
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            /* Call this function on every change of myCheck.
               Since it is bound to #mycheck, inside the function
               'this' refers to the checkbox, and $(this) is the
               jQuery object mapping the checkbox.
            */
            $('#mycheck').on('change', function(e) {
                $.post(
                    'test.php',
                    {
                         cmd        : "set",
                         state      : $(this).prop("checked"),
                         timestamp  : new Date().getTime(),
                         hello      : "world"
                    },
                    function(reply, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (!reply.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
                            console.log("the server replied with no message");
                            return;
                        }
                        console.log("the server replied: " + reply.message);
                    }
                ).fail(function(e) {
                    alert("Something went wrong");
                });
            });

            /* Now we also want to know what the status is NOW. */
            $.post(
                'test.php',
                {
                     cmd        : "get",
                     timestamp  : new Date().getTime()
                },
                function(reply, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (!reply.hasOwnProperty('state')) {
                        console.log("the server replied with no state");
                        return;
                    }
                    // If the server replied TRUE we set state to true.
                    // Else to false.
                    $('#mycheck').prop('checked', reply.state);
                }).fail(function(e) {
                    alert("Something went wrong");
                });

        });
    </script>
</html>
```

PHP side we will receive commands into test.php:

```
<!-- lang: lang-php5 -->
<?php
    function reply($reply) {
        Header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
        die(json_encode($reply));
    }
    function replyError($message) {
        return reply(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $message));
    }
    function replySuccess($data, $message = '') {
        return reply(array_merge(
            array('status' => 'success', 'message' => $message),
            $data
        ));
    }

    array_key_exists('cmd', $_POST) || replyError('cmd not set');

    switch($_POST['cmd']) {
        case 'set':
            $fp = fopen('state.txt', 'w');
            $state = in_array($_POST['state'], array(1, "1", "true", true));
            fwrite($fp, $state ? "CHECKED" : "NOT CHECKED");
            fclose($fp);
            replySuccess(array('state' => $state));
        case 'get':
            if (!file_exists('state.txt')) {
                $state = false;
            } else {
                $text = file_get_contents('state.txt');
                $state = ('CHECKED' == $text);
            }
            replySuccess(array('state' => $state));
        default:
            replyError("cmd={$_POST['cmd']} is not recognized");
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. I tried the code you sent, using 3 files(html,php, state.txt) and changed the url/id's of the checkbox. However it still doesn't seem to work correctly, what is the next step that i need to do? Thanks in advance

Comment: "doesn't seem to work correctly" is not very informative :-). I would be forced to answer "your code seems to need fixing". I'll add something about debugging.

Comment: Thanks again, i checked and the selectors and that's working fine. manually adressing .post also seems to working. I don't get what i need to do with adressing $.post. it seems to adress the Jquery file. If I understand you correctly, i now have loaded all the recourses needed. But i now have to sent the checkbox state to the AJAX using a HTTP post? Do you have any suggestions how/where i can find information about this. I think im googling on the wrong searchwords.

Comment: There are several jQuery tutorials (just google for that). I've included a barebone example which I tried and checked to be working; you can start by adapting that.

Comment: Thanks for  the example. However i've been trying to debug it for a day now.. But still im getting the error "something went wrong" which indicates that the jquery .post function is not working i guess? Also because the example works for  you and doesnt work for me scares me a bit. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Check with Firebug or WebTools what gets actually passed to the server, and what the answer is. 'Something went wrong' means a server error, such as 403 or 404 or 500. You need to verify which is it. It could be any of several things - a wrong mod_rewrite directive, a botched PHP setting, a proxy quirk.